# How to apply a function in parallelized fashion on all the columns of RDD(spark dataframe)?

Tags: python, function, parallel-processing, pyspark, rdd

I created a function(func) that accepts 2 inputs:

```
1. A 2 dimensional array - X
2. A 1 dimensional array - Y
```

I am able to carry out the desired operation, by converting RDD into pandas dataframe and then creating np.array(pandas datframe) as input X to func.

Let's say X has 10 cols. I want to process all 10 cols in parallel fashion So that I can call func for each of 10 cols at same time. How can I achieve it using RDD dataframe using pyspark in order to get the output of function for all 10 cols?

Answer (score 0):

1. RDD parallelize row-wise not column wise
2. 10 rows is not enough to use pyspark, it would take you more time than doing it locally
3. The function you are looking for on RDDs is `map`: `my_rdd.map(lambda x: func(x,y))` where `x` a row of `my_rdd`

You can do [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) in python

Comment: I added 10 cols as an example. Actual number of cols are about 10000. I want to apply the function on these 10000 cols in parallelized fashion

Comment: Then `map`, you have to transpose your array first. If you want to use dataframes instead of RDD you can put `func` in a `UDF`